# php fail to upload file

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with uploading file with PHP. The html code is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="action.php">
    <input type="file" name="file"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

and the PHP segment is

```
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0){
    $result['status'] = -1;
    $result['message'] = 'Unknown Error';
}
else{
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    $savepath = '/CSV Files/'.$file["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$savepath);
}
```

The problem is the `$result['status']` is not -1, but the `$file` is a null. And the strange thing is, the code worked well days ago, and suddenly died recently.Hope somebody could help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: show us `print_r($_FILES)`;

Comment: print_r($file); what does it print?

Comment: How does code suddenly stop working? Climate change?

Comment: print_r($_FILES) says true.

Comment: Sidenote: You're using an absolute path `$savepath = '/CSV Files/'.$file["name"];` which may not work. If running your code from the root, change it to `$savepath = 'CSV Files/'.$file["name"];` without the leading `/` while making sure the folder has write permissions set. You should also consider not using a space between `CSV` and `Files` but using an underscore. @CharlesDou

Comment: how can `print_r($_FILES)` return 'true ?

Comment: [`Time to read the manual - Do click here()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Comment: oh,sorry, printed the wrong thing. var_dump($_FILES) says "array(0) { }"

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to add `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="design.php">
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: May be the reason for upload  folder path

Comment: Well, I didn't provide the full path in here, but I am sure the path itself has no problem. The problem is $_FILES is empty.

Comment: print_r($_FILES); what is the output

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) says "array(0) {}" and print_r($_FILES) says "Array()"